# Pull querystring from cgi-bin with mod_rewrite and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a file path that looks like this: /cgi-bin/folder/script.cgi?t=1&u=http://domain.com/url/url-2/

What I want to do is create a rewrite rule to pull the querystring u= and then redirect to that URL, I've been working for a while on this with no success.

```
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/folder/script.cgi?t=1&u=(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Above is an example of one of my "solutions" that obviously didn't work. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+cgi-bin/folder/script\.cgi\?t=1&u=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]
```